# Parallax Scrolling do not work on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

The problem is,

- Parallax scrolling is working on desktop
- Parallax scrolling works, when I resize browser, and make it same size as mobile
- But it do not work on mobile device

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/)

And here is my code

```css
/* Index Page body CSS */
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
 
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/87hTDiay2N2qWyX4Ds7ybXi9h8I.jpg');
    min-height: 200px;
 
}

/* Second  Parallex image */
.bgimg-2 {
    background-image: url("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/8uO0gUM8aNqYLs1OsTBQiXu0fEv.jpg");
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg-1"></div> 

<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>

<div class="bgimg-2"></div> 

<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
<p>Hello Everyone, Thanks for helping me</p>
```

Comment: Use height for images rather than min-height and width:100%. Then check your page on the browser.

Comment: Still not working @Saurav

Comment: Ok, don't worry. You just try background:url("https://image.jpg") fixed center; background-size:cover; height:200px; width:100%;  rather than background-image.

Comment: @Saurav sir, you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/2/

If yes, then now parallex scrolling is not even working on desktop

Comment: No, you have to try it by replacing your whole css with this. It will work on my system. Hope it will work on your system also. Try it.

Comment: `background-attachment: fixed;` will not support on most of mobile devices  browsers as of today - check for more info - http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment

Comment: @Saurav Did u mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/3/

It is working on desktop but not on mobile

Comment: Yes, but you have to remove backgound-position and background-attachment from your code also. Tell me one thing in which browser you will  run your webpage.

Comment: Still not working https://jsfiddle.net/1m25rdw1/4/

And, i am using Chrome on android, latest version @Saurav

Comment: Ok, just try this in responsive style sheet.   @media screen and (max-width: 479px){

.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, {
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: auto;
   }
}

Comment: Sorry, there is one mistake use backgound-attachment:fixed; on above code

Comment: Still not working @Saurav

Comment: Have you used !important with background-attachment like this, background-attachment: fixed !important;

Comment: If still it will not work then use this                                                                     .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2 {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}     in responsive screen size.